# Group objects based on month with using date attribute within object

Tags: java, sorting, date

I have a requirement to group objects based on month. I call a service which returns list of objects which has date attribute (`RegisteredOn` in below response). Now I need group those objects based on month.

**Output should be:**

```
January 2017
object1
object2

Feburary 2017
Object3
Object4
```

Below is the service response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <QueryLeadsResponseMessage schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.discovery.co.za/leads" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.discovery.co.za/leads/wellness">
        <LeadProfile>
            <LeadReferenceNumber>16997345</LeadReferenceNumber>
            .............
            <RegisteredOn>2017-01-19T14:08:21.000+02:00</RegisteredOn>
            <LeadProduct>
                ----------
            </LeadProduct>
        </LeadProfile>
        <LeadProfile>
            --------
            <RegisteredOn>2017-01-19T14:09:05.000+02:00</RegisteredOn>
            <LeadProduct>
                ---------
            </LeadProduct>
        </LeadProfile>

        <LeadProfile>
            --------
            <RegisteredOn>2017-02-19T14:09:05.000+02:00</RegisteredOn>
            <LeadProduct>
                ---------
            </LeadProduct>
        </LeadProfile>

        <LeadProfile>
            --------
            <RegisteredOn>2017-02-19T14:09:05.000+02:00</RegisteredOn>
            <LeadProduct>
                ---------
            </LeadProduct>
        </LeadProfile>


    </QueryLeadsResponseMessage>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: It’s a bit broad as it stands. What have you tried? What did your research turn up, in in which way was it insufficient for your purpose?

Comment: I am thinking, your `RegisteredOn` values look like `OffsetDateTime` from a Java perspective (really they are just ISO 8601), so represent them as such. Use `YearMonth.from(registeredOn)` to get the year and month alone (such as February 2017). Use a stream and `Stream.groupingBy()` to group by year and month.

Comment: Is it OK to use the time zone offset from the SOAP? If those attributes can have any zone offset and you just take the month value from the string, you may be sorting them into an order that disagrees with chronological order. Or would you prefer to count months in UTC, for instance?

Comment: What's your java version? Do you use some specific API for date/time handling? Any code that you have tried?

Comment: The RegisteredOn is XMLGregorianCalendar and not offsetDateTime. I dint try any code as I am not usre of where to start. The reults are alreday sorted for 3 months, so there was not need to use date comparator. Just need to group them according to months. Java Version is 7